# JavaScript Period Functionality: How do I setup a library like jQuery did

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class, api-design

## Intro# (Edited)

Hey everyone, I'm setting up a JavaScript library that is designed to us AJAX and connect to a number of PHP, which then connects to the database. (fairly certain that this is what you call an API). To make things easier for my team, though, I wanted to setup some sort of initialization object like the **$** in jQuery. Can someone help point me to the right data type?

## Example

```
// Pull new user data from fields
var username = $.("#usernamefield").val();
var password = $.("#userpassfield").val();

// Send data to library through
API.AddUser(username, password);

// Sorry for any syntax errors, this is just example code
```

## Potential Solution

I did consider using a class system, but I did some research, and it seems like there may be a better way. Can someone help explain how jQuery setup their library?

## Clarificaton

A few people asked why I don't just use jQuery. Well, actually, I am. I'm using jQuery and building this separate library for uploading information with PHP. They two are Apples and Oranges, but I do want to have an initializer like jQueries "$" - Can somebody explain how they did it?

Comment: if you want to do something like jQuery, why not just use jQuery .... in your "Example", how does `API` relate to `$` ? [zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) is supposedly a lean jQuery-like library, the dev source code is commented heavily, so you could "learn" from that

Comment: I am using jQuery, but I also want to build some of my own functions that are held in an object.

Comment: I never realized how dynamic JavaScript was. Coming from a Python background, it is a bit crazy. I'll revise my question to be more precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you should do it:

In a JS template that you could call API.js, you will have the following:

```
 ;(function($){

    /* ========================================================
    /* Global variables */
    /* =======================================================*/
    var api = null;

   /* ========================================================
    /* Ajax calls */
    /* =======================================================*/

    var API = function(args)
    {
        // Api methods 

        this.AddUser = function (username, password)
        {

            //To do Ajax call
        }

        this.DeleteUser = function(id)
        {
            //To do Ajax call
        }

        // ... More api methods
    };

   /* ========================================================
    /* Main function */
    /* =======================================================*/

    jQuery.fn.API = function( args )
    {
        api = new API(args);
        return api;
    };


})(jQuery);
```

Then when you need to make an Ajax call, you just need to initialise an API object with any required arguments as follows:

```
$(function() {
     //Note: you can pass global arguments.
    var API = $().API();

    //You can then make your api calls with required values

    // Pull new user data from fields
    var username = $("#usernamefield").val();
    var password = $("#userpassfield").val();

    // Send data to library through
    API.AddUser(username, password);

});
```

Comment: I did update my code to something similar.

    var API;
    API.AddUser = function() { /*Stuff*/ }

Would this be an effective method?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be. It is all about what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you have in mind but it seems like to you want to set up a function with state information.  One way to do this is to put it inside a closure.  Something like this perhaps:...

```
`
 var connect = function(username,password){

                  //perhaps do some stuff here

                  return function(a,b,c){
                            //do connection stuff using 
                            // username, password and a,b,c
                         }
               };
`

Then you can set up your connection function:

`
  fredsConnection = connect( 'fred', 'piglet');
`
```

This gives you a connection function with Fred's credentials built in so that now any time he needs to connect:

```
`
fredsConnection('widgets', 'v2','green')
```

`
He can call his connection function and just pass the necessary data